# How to set HADOOP_CLASSPATH for Oozie MapReduce action

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I can run my `MapReduce` job manually to load data into `Hbase` without any issue,

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/../hbase/*
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:./*
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

hadoop jar MyLoader-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar inputFolder outputFolder
```

I tried to set this up in a `Oozie` job as a `MapReduce` action and it gave me the `ClassNotFound` error.

I think it's because I didn't export `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` for the Oozie job. Does anybody know how to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` for `Oozie MapReduce` action?

Thanks a lot!

Tom

Comment: Add HADOOP_CLASSPATH export statements in `/home/username/.bashrc`

Comment: Have you tried using Oozie's ShareLib?